# How to pack Apache2 + PHP in a single application in Linux?

Tags: linux, server

we have a web site built on PHP + MongoDB. And we want to provide this as a self-hosted solution. This way we have to ask our customers to install a web-server, PHP, some extensions, MongoDB with PHP drivers, etc. It is not a big issue for any Pro linux administrator, but it becomes a hell if the customer doesn't have a linux specialist.

Is there is a way to pack all applications with configs into one single app ready to launch in «one click» (like WAMP for Windows)?

Comment: You need to build packages - .deb (debian/ubuntu/mint/etc) and .rpm (redhat/centos/fedora/etc) containing your application.  As dependencies for this package you'll need to specify relevant versions of apache httpd and php.

Comment: Please do not use every single tag you think about in your questions ! It has nothing to do with PHP itself !

Comment: I removed PHP tag, but nevetheless I don't agree with you, because the question is about how to pack PHP application with dfferent env. under linux

Comment: @IliyaGarakh Thx for removing the tag :) and for info, event if your question has something about PHP doesn't mean you can use it's tag because the PHP tag is for problems/question about PHP it self, your question is 99.99% about server configuration and ... and has nothing to do with the PHP programming :)

Comment: @Soheyl now it makes sense, I'll take it into my account, thanks!